# Overflow integer multiplication in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, integer-overflow

I am trying to implement murmurHash in MATLAB which I have already a code in C++. In C++ code:

```
static const uint32_t c1 = 0xcc9e2d51; //(3432918353 in decimal)
        .
        .
        .
k1 *= c1;// k1 is 6649713 before multiplication
```

After multiplication it gives the result 3117918145(which is mod(3432918353*6649713,4294967296) in order to keep it in bounds of the 32-bit unsigned integer).

But, in MATLAB, it gives the result 4294967296 which is max for 32-bit unsigned integer. Is there anyway to overcome this problem by not converting the numbers into 64-bit and calculating modulo wrt 4294967296 (32-bit max)?

Comment: I wanted to suggest looking at [`gcd`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcd.html) but your number being prime it is not going to help. I don't know any other way than the one you mentioned already. You could wrap it in a helper function though: `multOverflow = @(x,y) uint32( mod( uint64(x)*uint64(y),4294967296  ) )`

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought exactly, but I found conversion from 64-bit inefficient(because I'm obsessive :)).